# Horizontal cyclinder - Canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

I am trying to  create horizontal cylinder. I have found the below link which is used for creating vertical cylinder.

[How to draw a cylinder on html5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498521/how-to-draw-a-cylinder-on-html5-canvas)

can someone tell me the changes to create a horizontal cylinder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if you have a drawing you want to rotate, you can use transforms.

Transforms move, rotate (and scale) the canvas without the need to recode your desired drawing.

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/RU26r/

This transform will rotate your original drawing 90 degrees:

```
drawRotatedCylinder(100,100,50,30,90);

function drawRotatedCylinder(x,y,w,h,degreeAngle){

  // save the context in its unrotated state
  context.save();

  // translate to the rotation point
  // your object will rotate around the rotation point
  // so if you want it to rotate from the center then 
  // translate to x+width/2, y+height/2

  context.translate(x+w/2,y+h/2);

  // rotate by 90 degrees
  // rotate() takes radians, so convert to radians
  // with radians==degrees*Math.PI/180

  context.rotate(degreeAngle*Math.PI/180);

  // draw your original shape--no recoding required!

  drawCylinder(-w/2,-h/2,w,h);

  // restore the context to its untransformed state

  context.restore();

}
```

Comment: thanks. What is the difference between scale and transform?          Why did you call drawCylinder(- w/2, -h/2, w , h); ?

Comment: "Transforming" is an umbrella term that includes context.rotate, context.scale and context.translate.  So scale is a type of transform.  context.translate(x,y) resets the [0,0] coordinate of the canvas to [x,y].  Since your drawCylinder in drawn starting in its top left corner, `-w/2` and `-h/2` will push the center of the cylinder to the 0,0 coordinate.  That way the cylinder rotates around its centerpoint rather then rotating around its top left corner. Cheers!

Comment: markE: :) .  If I don't want to rotate the cylinder, I have to replace degree angle to 90'? Why you didn't use context.closePath() at the end?                                                        with this horizontal cylinder How to make a sausage shape(   ) using this code. I want to make the circle to look like ) instead of () at the right end.

Comment: Yes, if you just want the cylinder at 90 degrees==horizontal, just drawRotatedCylinder(x,y,w,h,90);  BTW, I just used the link in your question to draw the cylinder.  If you want a shape like this (__) with lines connecting top and bottom, the draw is much simpler--just arc+line+arc+closePath:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/3j27X/

Comment: I want to use horizontal cylinder code and I want to remove only '(' at the right end to create sausage shape.It should look like (___). If I use quadraticCurveTO, the curve ')' is not similar to cylinder curve ')'. Do I have to run the loop for 180 degree instead of 360 degree?

Comment: You can use a bezierCurveTo to get a more refined arc like the one in your original link.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: I tried using bezier curve to draw cylinder. The curve is proper in the center. There is a slight deviation in top and bottom of the curve.

Comment: You can get symmetrical curves by mirroring the control points against the horizontal centerline for the top and bottom curves.

Comment: ctx. bezierCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + height, x + width * 16/17, y + height); or  ctx.bezierCurveTo(x + width,y,x+width, y + height/2,x+width,y+height/2); ctx.bezierCurveTo(x+width,y+height,x+width*16/17,y+height,x+width*16/17, y+height);  total width =  17.                                 I want to start the curve at (x +width*16/17,y).

Comment: How to draw horizontal cylinder without using rotate and translate?

Comment: @Ajaii.  It's much more difficult to not use rotate and translate.  You would have to use trigonometry to calculate the proper positions of the lines & curves.  So I would use the tools of rotate & translate that the canvas offers :-)

Comment: if i use rotate and translate , the shape is not displaying in the correct position and width of the shape is reduced and oval is very large. Is it possible to use Math.sin and Math.cos without canvas rotate method?

Comment: Hmmm...neither translate or rotate will change the shape.  Scaling will change the shape.  Anyway, Yes(!), you can use trigonometry--that's what canvas does behind the scenes.  A trig tutorial is beyond the scope of a stackoverflow answer, but there are many, many resources on the web to help you learn trig.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: thanks :) . In my project, I have to create many geometry shapes.